# Flag Off topic -> migration gives only the option gaming-meta

Tags: support, flags

I just flagged this question [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/205389/sc2ranks-with-wordpress) as off topic.

I tried to use the option "this question belongs to an other site of the stackexchange network. But the only option I got there is gaming-meta, as seen in this screenshot: [image: Off-Topic reasons]
I then chose an other reason for the flag.

But why is gaming-meta the only option here?

Comment: Yep, as intended.  Very rarely are questions worth migrating.  This one seems to be one of those that GameDev would automatically close, so there's no point in doing so.

Comment: Of course GameDev would also be the the wrong place for that question. But stackoverflow or maybe some other site about web design would be the right place.

Comment: I'm quite sure SO would reject it even quicker than GameDev would; the user has displayed zero effort to attempt to resolve this themselves, and for questions to work at SO, that's an absolute minimum.

Comment: status-by-design I'm afraid

Comment: @MBraedley How can this be a duplicate? The OP has not specifically referred to specific sites to handle a migration path; rather, he is curious why there are no other paths besides meta.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the number of questions we get that are worth migrating elsewhere is *vanishingly small*.

Adding a migration path to another site would greatly increase the number of bad migrations, at little actual benefit. When a question legitimately needs to go to another SE site, a moderator can handle it with ease, so just raise a custom flag, and a mod will review it.

Comment: As the flags have to be approved by a experienced user, I don't see that big of a risk about bad migrations. But I see your point about the vanishingly small number.